# Añadir marginBottom a un TextView desde Activity

Tags: java, android

Recojo los datos de un array y añado por cada elemento del array un TextView al Activity, hasta ahí todo bien, pero no consigo averiguar como añadir un marginBottom desde el activity, de hecho no se ni que tengo que usar y no lo encuentro en ejemplos:

```
for(int i=0; i<borrachos.length; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(ShowChistesActivity.this);
        textView.setText(borrachos[i]);
        textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        textView.setId(i);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BrackgroundChistes));
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

Comment: marginBottom ó paddingBottom para alguno en específico o para todos?

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente necesitas crear un LayoutParams

**Codigo para ti**

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layoutParams.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 10);

        for(int i=0; i<borrachos.length; i++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(borrachos[i]);
            textView.setId(i);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            linearLayout.addView(textView, layoutParams);
        }
```

**Margenes**

[image: Marges]

**Aqui la foto**

[image: Resultado]